# Phonegap serve command not recognized (osx)

Tags: macos, cordova

I've just installed phonegap in osx, with no errors. Created a demo app, and then tried to use the "phonegap serve" command to serve it to my phone (running Phonegap developer app).

All I get is this error:

`error  'serve' is not a phonegap command. See 'phonegap help'`

Any advice?

Comment: Had the same problem... phonegap version installed was 0.9.4 (isn't that strange?). Just `sudo npm update -g phonegap ` as Arthur Lorent had already suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to do a `phonegap -v`
If the version is earlier than 5.1.1-0.29.0 you should make the command
`npm update -g phonegap`
Then try again `phonegap serve`, this should work.

Comment: In face, version installed by default was 0.9.4 with missing command. Is it normal that it installs such an old version?

Comment: I do not know but I had the same problem and found this solution. This phonegap version is quite new and in beta for some parts of it. This may be the cause of the version of the initial install